# Property not getting passed to other class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, properties

First time actually trying to implement properties and it seems that I'm missing something fundamental that I'm not aware of. I'm trying to pass a bool value from once script to another and have it constantly up using the `Update()`.

In `GameManager.cs` I'm checking for player idle and when it the player idles it sets a property `UserActive` to false. In `PreCountdownTimer.cs` I'm just testing to see if `_userActive` is updating, but it is not. Why is the property value in `GameManager()` not passing to `PreCountdownTimer()` ?

**GameManager.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static GameManager Instance = null;

    public Object introScene;

    private bool _userActive;
    public bool UserActive { get; set; }
    private bool _onIntroScreen;
    public bool OnIntroScreen { get; set; }

    public GameObject preCountdownTimerPrefab;
    private GameObject _preCountdownTimerInstance;
    private float _preCountdownLength;
    public float PreCountdownLength { get; protected set; }
    private float _preCountdownInterval;
    public float PreCountdownInterval { get; protected set; }

    private float _checkMousePositionTimingInterval = 0.1f;
    private Vector3 _currentMousePosition;
    private Vector3 _prevMousePosition;
    private Scene _currentScene;

    void Awake()
    {
        if (Instance == null)
            Instance = this;
        else if (Instance != null)
            Destroy(gameObject);
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }

    void OnEnable()
    {
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnSceneLoaded;
    }

    void OnSceneLoaded(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode)
    {
        _currentScene = scene;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        PreCountdownLength = 5.0f;
        PreCountdownInterval = 1.0f;

        _onIntroScreen = true;
        _userActive = false;

        _prevMousePosition = Input.mousePosition;

        InvokeRepeating("LastMousePosition", 0, _checkMousePositionTimingInterval); 
    }

    void Update()
    {
        _currentMousePosition = Input.mousePosition;

        // CHECK FOR PLAYER IDLE
        if (_currentScene.name != introScene.name)
        {
            _onIntroScreen = false;

            if (_currentMousePosition != _prevMousePosition)
            {
                _userActive = true;
            }
            else
            {
                _userActive = false;
            }       
        }
        else if (_currentScene.name == introScene.name)
        {
            _onIntroScreen = true;
        }

        // IF IDLE START PRE-COUNT TIMER ELSE DESTROY
        if (!_userActive && !_onIntroScreen)
        {
            if (_preCountdownTimerInstance == null)
                _preCountdownTimerInstance = Instantiate(preCountdownTimerPrefab);
        }
        else if (_userActive)
        {
            if (_preCountdownTimerInstance != null)
                Destroy(_preCountdownTimerInstance);
        }
    }

    void LastMousePosition()
    {
        _prevMousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
    }
}
```

**PreCountdownTimer.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PreCountdownTimer : MonoBehaviour {

    private IEnumerator preCounter;

    private float _preCountdownInterval;
    private bool _preCountdownActive;
    private bool _userActive;
    private bool _onIntroScreen;
    private float _timerLength;

    void Start()
    {
        _timerLength = GameManager.Instance.PreCountdownLength;
    }

   void Update()
    {
        _userActive = GameManager.Instance.UserActive;
        _onIntroScreen = GameManager.Instance.OnIntroScreen;

        Debug.Log("User Activity: " + _userActive);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the PreCountdownTimer.Update method called from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `GameManager` you have a field and a property :

```
private bool _userActive;              // field
public bool UserActive { get; set; }   // property
```

Those are not connected. When you set `_userActive` it has no effect on `UserActive`. In `PreCountdownTimer` you check `GameManager.Instance.UserActive`. The fix is to either connect the field and the property:

```
private bool _userActive;
public bool UserActive 
{ 
    get
    {
        return _userActive;
    } 
    set
    {
        _userActive = value;
    } 
}
```

Or remove the field `_userActive` at all and just set the property (I would prefer this way, since you currently have no need for the field):

```
void Start()
{
    PreCountdownLength = 5.0f;
    PreCountdownInterval = 1.0f;

    _onIntroScreen = true;
    UserActive = false;

    _prevMousePosition = Input.mousePosition;

    InvokeRepeating("LastMousePosition", 0, _checkMousePositionTimingInterval); 
}

void Update()
{
    _currentMousePosition = Input.mousePosition;

    // CHECK FOR PLAYER IDLE
    if (_currentScene.name != introScene.name)
    {
        _onIntroScreen = false;

        if (_currentMousePosition != _prevMousePosition)
        {
            UserActive = true;
        }
        else
        {
            UserActive = false;
        }       
    }
    else if (_currentScene.name == introScene.name)
    {
        _onIntroScreen = true;
    }

    // IF IDLE START PRE-COUNT TIMER ELSE DESTROY
    if (!UserActive && !_onIntroScreen)
    {
        if (_preCountdownTimerInstance == null)
            _preCountdownTimerInstance = Instantiate(preCountdownTimerPrefab);
    }
    else if (UserActive)
    {
        if (_preCountdownTimerInstance != null)
            Destroy(_preCountdownTimerInstance);
    }
}
```

The same problem is true for your other properties in `GameManager`. Also I woul recommend to work with the properties (also in `GameManager`) instead of the fields. This way you have more control about what is happening. Only directly work with the fields when it is absolutely necessary.

Comment: Don't you destroy `PreCountdownTimer` when the user is active? I mean this code: `else if (_userActive)
        {
            if (_preCountdownTimerInstance != null)
                Destroy(_preCountdownTimerInstance);
        }`

Answer (score 1):

In GameManager you have defined

```
private bool _userActive;
public bool UserActive { get; set; }
```

The first is a private field, while the second is a public property, they have similar names but you have not linked them together so they are both standalone.

You have two options,

1)   Remove the private `_userActive` and only use the public property
2)   Make the public property use the private field such as below

```
private bool _userActive;
public bool UserActive 
{ 
    get
    {
       return _userActive;
    }; 
    set
    {
       this._userActive = value;
    };
}
```

The second option is most useful if you need to do some validation, reformatting, or trigger other actions and either retrieving or setting the value.

Comment: Sorry, I was writing at the same time and did not see your answer until I had posted!